# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/support/PageableExecutionUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Getting this exception

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/support/PageableExecutionUtils
```

When I use **@AutoWired** twice in Spring Controller. 
I am using **Spring-data-jpa** of version **2.0.0.M1** 
Do I have to downgrade this Spring-data-jpa or any other option for using @AutoWired twice in Spring controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your pom.xml and the controller class

Comment: Thank you. I solved this issue by upgrading spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE to spring-data-commons-2.0.0.M1. Since I am using spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.M1. Now I can able to use multiple @Autowired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/support/PageableExecutionUtils
```

PageableExecutionUtils class must be present in spring-data-commons.So when you face this exception do check the source for PageableExecutionUtils class. If not present, upgrade the spring-data-commons jar.

Initially I used spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE, upgraded to spring-data-commons-2.0.0.M1.

Comment: This helped me with a similar exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable"`. spring-data-commons.jar was just absent in the classpath.

Comment: I'm getting this on spring-data-commons-3.0.0